# How can I do this [complex] table update using only SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm in the middle of doing some database conversions to prepare the database for my app's next version update. There's one specific scenario I'm running into that I have working as C# code in LINQPad (LINQPad is running the conversion), but it's waaaaayyyy slow and I want to try and convert it to direct SQL. Otherwise it looks like the conversion will take about two days using the C# code, and I can't disable the app for that long to make it happen. In the scenario I'm trying to update a column that didn't exist before. Consider the following tables:

**Table J** (for @maccettura)

```
------
| Id |
------
| 1  |
------
```

**Table P**

```
-------------------------
| Id | JId | DateAt     |
-------------------------
| 1  | 1   | 2017-01-01 |
| 2  | 1   | 2017-02-01 |
| 3  | 1   | 2017-03-01 |
-------------------------
```

**Table D**

```
------------
| Id | JId |
------------
| 1  | 1   |
| 2  | 1   |
| 3  | 1   |
------------
```

**Table DR**

```
---------------------
| Id | DId | DateAt |
---------------------
| 1  | 1   | NULL   |
| 2  | 1   | NULL   |
| 3  | 2   | NULL   |
| 4  | 2   | NULL   |
| 5  | 3   | NULL   |
| 6  | 3   | NULL   |
---------------------
```

I want to update table **DR** so that the dates are filled in and the data looks like this:

```
-------------------------
| Id | DId | DateAt     |
-------------------------
| 1  | 1   | 2017-01-01 |
| 2  | 1   | 2017-02-01 |
| 3  | 2   | 2017-01-01 |
| 4  | 2   | 2017-02-01 |
| 5  | 3   | 2017-01-01 |
| 6  | 3   | 2017-02-01 |
-------------------------
```

I just can't seem to be able to express it in SQL though. I've tried messing around with selecting into temp tables, trying to match up by the row number, etc., but I'm just not skilled enough with SQL to make it work. I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. If it makes any difference, here's how the UI form looks like:

```
           -----------------               -------------
           | D.Id  | D.Id  |               | 1 | 2 | 3 |
---------------------------- => ------------------------
| P.DateAt | DR.Id | DR.Id |    | 1/1/2017 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| P.DateAt | DR.Id | DR.Id |    | 1/2/2017 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
----------------------------    ------------------------
```

I'm trying to do all of this because in the app update I sort the **DR** rows by the `DateAt` column. In the current version if a user adds a date out of order, someone goes in an rearranges all of the data so the dates are in order. As you can imagine it's a huge waste of time, which is why I want to make it irrelevant what the entry order is, but display it as it should be.

The only "relationship" I have is the order of the `Id` columns in the **P** and **DR** tables. The first **P** row is the first date, and the last **P** row is the last date. The first **DR** row is for the first date, and the last **DR** row is for the last date.

Oh, and the database is SQL Server 2012. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Am I missing something?  How do you expect to get anything from table `P`?  If `DR` has a `DId` then you can connect to `D`, but where is the PK/FK for `P`?

Comment: @maccettura, sorry, I guess I wasn't awake enough to compose a full question, but yes you are correct there is a parent table **J** that I omitted. Tables **P** and **D** are related to it.

Comment: Should the last row really be `6|4|2017-02-01`?  And not `6|4|2017-01-01`?

Comment: @AaronDietz, my mistake, it should actually be `6|3|2017-02-01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
UPDATE DR
SET DR.DATEAT = P.DATEAT
FROM (SELECT ID, DId, DATEAT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DId ORDER BY ID) RN
      FROM DR) DR
JOIN P ON P.ID = DR.RN
```

Basically this is saying, if it is the first row for a new `DId`, then use the first date from table `P`, then second row to second date, etc.

`SELECT` to see the logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID, DId, DATEAT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DId ORDER BY ID) RN
      FROM DR) DR
JOIN P ON P.ID = DR.RN
```

`SELECT` results:

[image: SELECT results]

`DR` after update:

[image: DR after update]

**EDIT**
It sounds like the `P` table does not have reliable `id`s.  You can create those with another use of `ROW_NUMBER()` if needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID, DId, DateAt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DId ORDER BY ID) RN
  FROM DR) DR
JOIN (SELECT DateAt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateAt ASC) as ID
      FROM P 
     ) P ON P.ID = DR.RN
```

Comment: thank you for the example! I'm testing out the `SELECT` on a freshly restored and scrubbed backup, but I'm getting no results. I think it's because of the `JOIN` on **P**. **P** would also need to have row number to align it to **DR**. **DR** otherwise looks like it should. And if I may be rude for a moment, may I ask you to also relate **P** and **D** to their parent **J** table, otherwise I have a feeling it's going to become a free for all when the update runs? Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c Np, but I'm confused that it isn't working.  I went ahead and created those tables and took screenshots of my results.  You can disregard the final record, I used `DId = 4` before I saw your edit that it should be `3`.

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c About table **J**, it appears it can be joined in as `JOIN J on J.ID = P.JID`, but it won't affect the update. :P

Comment: Ok, so, I made a separate database and recreated the tables as in my example, and you're right, it does work, but to a point. Where it falls apart is when the `P.Id` is a higher number than the `D.Rn`. For example, take `P.Id` 2 and change it to 2000 (or anything else really) and then re-run the query. Now you should have half of the results because the `D.Rn` no longer aligns with `P.Id`.

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c Yeah, the only way `P.id = 2000` would be used, is if there is a "2000th" record for a given `DId` in DR.  I understood the question as **For each DId in DR, the first record should have the first date in the P table (ie. Pid = 1).  The second record should have the second date (ie. Pid = 2)** ... If that logic is wrong, I misunderstood the question.  Does the **P** table look different in reality than in your example?

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c Edited my answer to spoof a row number for **P** instead of the ID.  I really feel less comfortable with this because I'm concerned that I don't understand the question as well as I thought, but give it a shot.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I did, except I named the row number columns as `Index` because it made me feel more comfortable: `JOIN (SELECT [P].[Id], [P].[DateAt], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [P].[Id]) AS [Index], [P].[JId] FROM [P]) AS [P] ON ([P].[Index] = [DR].[Index])`. It's skipping P.2000 and going to P.3, which I believe is the correct behavior. I also added a join to **J**, but I'm not sure it's correct: `JOIN [J] ON (([J].[Id] = [P].[JId]) AND ([J].[Id] = [DR].[JId]))`. I'll test this against the backup db and see what results I get.

Comment: @Gup3rSuR4c Right on, sounds like you're close!

Comment: Ok, so, I couldn't get it to work without isolating it down to a specific `J.Id`. It just wouldn't work. In the end I simulated a FOR loop which allowed me to isolate to a single `J.Id` at a time and it works. It took about 7 seconds to make the update vs how long the C# code was taking. I'm happy with it. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it! Now I need to go repeat this for a couple of other problem tables. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to backup your database first, but an update statement with a `from` clause should do what you need:

```sql
update dr
set
    dr.DateAt = p.DateAt
from
    p
where
    dr.id = p.id
```

**Performance Note:**

If you don't already have an index on `id` for both tables, you will probably want to add one before doing this. If your table is large, this would take a while if you're doing full table scans.